# regex - single char plural finding java

Tags: java, regex

String

```
The method according to claims 1 to 6
The method of claim 1,
```

my regex

```
\\bclaim\\s+(\\d+)
 it finding the digits after the word claim
```

if the word `claim` its finding the digit after the word
 in case the word `claims` its not finding

so i changed my regex

```
\\bclaim(?=s)\\s+(\\d+)
```

but its not finding claims
Let me know any other possibilities

Comment: I would use the count indicator as: \\bclaim[s]{0,1}\\s+(\\d+) Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a lookahead, just make `s` optional:

```
\\bclaims?\\s+(\\d+)
```

By using a lookahead `(?=s)` your regex is not consuming character `s` that comes after `claim` hence `\\s+` afterwards is not matched for the second line.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hD4lW7/1)

Comment: Just to add to the explanation: if the `(?=s)` is used, you require an `s` to be present right after the current position, but that means your pattern should also match and consume the character with either `.`, `\w`, `[a-zA-Z]`, `s`, etc. Since you need both `claim` and `claims`, the `s?` (one or zero `s`) is more reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

Hey just use the following regex,

```
String pattern = "\\bclaims?\\s+(\\d+)";
        Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
        Matcher m = r.matcher(str);
        if (m.find( )) 
            System.out.println(m.group());
```

Output:

```
claims 1
claim 1
```